# HTML5 getting the body of the page to fill the screen on its own

Tags: html

So pretty much i'm coding a webpage for A class and I cannot figure out how to make space so that the body expands on its own to the end of the page, so that I don't have all this extra space, I'll drop the html code and the css below so that you get what I'm talking about. Any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried margining and a lot of other stuff in the book and I cannot figure it out.

```css
body {
    background-color: #faf86f;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    color:rgb(47, 79, 219);
    background-image: url(bistro_logo.png);
    background-size: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat round;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px rgb(81, 177, 241);
}
#wrapper { 
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    border: 4px solid blue;
}


img { float:left; 

}
nav {
    flex:1;
    border: 4px solid rgb(47, 79, 219);
    
}
nav ul{ list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    
    
}
nav li {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
    

}
nav a:link { color:blue}
nav a:visited { color:rgb(96, 10, 175)}
nav a:hover { color:aqua}

main { 
    flex: 7;
    margin: auto;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    color:blueviolet;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    float: center;
    text-align-last: auto;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color:blue;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-style:oblique;
}
footer {
    border-top: 3px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.float {
    float: left;
    
}
@media(min-width: 800px) {
    #wrapper { width: 80%; 
        margin:auto;
    }
    nav li {
        display: inline;
        
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bistro Cafe - Home</title>
    <link href="bistro.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>The Bistro Cafe</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="bistro_home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="bistro_history.html">Bistro Cafe's History</a></li>
            <li><a href="bistro_specials.html">Bistro Specials</a></li>
            <li><a href="bistro_contact.html">Contact Bistro Cafe</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <p>The Bistro Cafe is located in the heart of Techieville! We specialize in good-ole home cooking. Our menu ranges from chicken dumplings to our famous fiesta burrito. Our breakfast menu is available all day. Please come by and share a meal with us. We are conveniently located on the corner of 5th and Hypertext Avenue.
            
        </p>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <a href="bistro_home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="bistro_history.html">Bistro Cafe's History</a>
        <a href="bistro_specials.html">Bistro Specials</a>
        <a href="bistro_contact.html">Contact Bistro Cafe</a>
        &copy; copyright 2022 <a href="mailto:jmmartin@mail.mccneb.edu">Josh Martin</a>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want the blue outline portion to stretch the height of the viewing window area? I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: yeah, I just don't want it to stop halfway on the page. I want it to bring the footer to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially misunderstood what you meant by "getting the body of the page to fill the screen on its own". Your `<body>` is already filling the page. What you're talking about is stretching `#wrapper` to fill `<body>`.

As with all things CSS, there are a variety of ways to accomplish this. One approach would be to:

- Set `min-height: calc(100vh - 8px)` on `#wrapper`. This makes it at least as tall as the viewport, subtracting 8px to account for the 4px borders.
- Make `#wrapper` a flex container. This sets up the ability for `main` to stretch to fill the available vertical space
- Set `flex: 1` on `main`. (Or `flex-grow: 1`, or `flex: 1 1 auto`). This allows main to stretch to fill the available space.
- Set `margin: 0` on body. (Without this you end up with 100vh plus the default margin, resulting in scrollbars.)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 8px);
}

main { 
  flex: 1;
}
```

Here's your sample snippet with the rules above added:

```css
body {
    background-color: #faf86f;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    color:rgb(47, 79, 219);
    background-image: url(bistro_logo.png);
    background-size: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat round;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px rgb(81, 177, 241);
}
#wrapper { 
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 8px); /* subtracting 8px to account for the 4px border */;
}

nav {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    border: 4px solid rgb(47, 79, 219);
    
}
nav ul{ list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    
    
}
nav li {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
    

}
nav a:link { color:blue}
nav a:visited { color:rgb(96, 10, 175)}
nav a:hover { color:aqua}

main { 
    flex: 1;
    margin: auto;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    color:blueviolet;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    float: center;
    text-align-last: auto;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color:blue;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-style:oblique;
}
footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
    border-top: 3px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.float {
    float: left;
    
}
@media(min-width: 800px) {
    #wrapper { width: 80%; 
        margin:auto;
    }
    nav li {
        display: inline;
        
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>The Bistro Cafe</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="bistro_home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="bistro_history.html">Bistro Cafe's History</a></li>
            <li><a href="bistro_specials.html">Bistro Specials</a></li>
            <li><a href="bistro_contact.html">Contact Bistro Cafe</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <p>The Bistro Cafe is located in the heart of Techieville! We specialize in good-ole home cooking. Our menu ranges from chicken dumplings to our famous fiesta burrito. Our breakfast menu is available all day. Please come by and share a meal with us. We are conveniently located on the corner of 5th and Hypertext Avenue.
            
        </p>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <a href="bistro_home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="bistro_history.html">Bistro Cafe's History</a>
        <a href="bistro_specials.html">Bistro Specials</a>
        <a href="bistro_contact.html">Contact Bistro Cafe</a>
        &copy; copyright 2022 <a href="mailto:jmmartin@mail.mccneb.edu">Josh Martin</a>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason it still won't fill the viewport

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick but if you want to make it responsive then you will have to work for it or just better to use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/) if you want responsiveness.

```css
body {
    background-color: #faf86f;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    color:rgb(47, 79, 219);
    background-image: url(bistro_logo.png);
    background-size: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat round;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px rgb(81, 177, 241);
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 97vh;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}


img { float:left; 

}
nav {
    flex:1;
    border: 4px solid rgb(47, 79, 219);
    
}
nav ul{ list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    
    
}
nav li {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
    

}
nav a:link { color:blue}
nav a:visited { color:rgb(96, 10, 175)}
nav a:hover { color:aqua}

main { 
    flex: 7;
    margin: auto;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    color:blueviolet;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    float: center;
    text-align-last: auto;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color:blue;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-style:oblique;
}
footer {
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
  width: 79%;
  margin-left: 10.5%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
}
.float {
    float: left;
    
}
@media(min-width: 800px) {
    #wrapper { width: 80%; 
        margin:auto;
    }
    nav li {
        display: inline;
        
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bistro Cafe - Home</title>
    <link href="bistro.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>The Bistro Cafe</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="bistro_home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="bistro_history.html">Bistro Cafe's History</a></li>
            <li><a href="bistro_specials.html">Bistro Specials</a></li>
            <li><a href="bistro_contact.html">Contact Bistro Cafe</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <p>The Bistro Cafe is located in the heart of Techieville! We specialize in good-ole home cooking. Our menu ranges from chicken dumplings to our famous fiesta burrito. Our breakfast menu is available all day. Please come by and share a meal with us. We are conveniently located on the corner of 5th and Hypertext Avenue.
            
        </p>
    </main>
</div>
    <footer>
        <a href="bistro_home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="bistro_history.html">Bistro Cafe's History</a>
        <a href="bistro_specials.html">Bistro Specials</a>
        <a href="bistro_contact.html">Contact Bistro Cafe</a>
        &copy; copyright 2022 <a href="mailto:jmmartin@mail.mccneb.edu">Josh Martin</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```